# Convert DateTime to specific format - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
new Date(1501796503599)
```

which returns the value

```
Fri Aug 04 2017 03:11:43 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I need the above value to be displayed as `"Today, 3:11 am"`. Is there a way to do this

Comment: Using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) is recommended.

Comment: you can simply check using javascript without any dependencies. var yourDate = new Date(1501796503599); var today = new Date(); var isToday = (today.toDateString() == yourDate.toDateString()); if(isToday){ //then print today date including time..}else{//your code here..}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var time = moment(1501796503599).calendar();
console.log(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: the support for file:// protocol issues in moment looks like it is still open, so that might add an additional complication depending on how he decides to use this solution.

Comment: Can you link the issue, please? @jidexl21

Answer (score 1):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) should be suitable for your needs.
Have a look at their documentation.

This should work for you:

```
moment().calendar();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check using javascript without any dependencies.

```
var yourDate = new Date(1501796503599); 
var today = new Date(); 
var isToday = (today.toDateString() == yourDate.toDateString()); 
if(isToday){
    yourDate = "Today, " + yourDate.toLocaleTimeString();
}
else{
  yourDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
               "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];


$(function(){
        var newDate = '';

            newDate = new Date(1501796503599)
        if (newDate != '')
            var str = newDate.getDate() + "-" + monthName[newDate.getMonth()] + "-" + newDate.getFullYear()+
           " " + newDate.getHours() + ":" + newDate.getMinutes() + ":" + newDate.getSeconds();

        console.log(str);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

try this one.